# Laravel Nova HasOne Relationship view and edit 2 models in single panel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a HasOne relationship between 2 models.

In Laravel Nova, is it possible to merge them into a single panel when viewing details, and update both model together when updating details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not officially supported in laravel nova. but there is a workaround to achieve it using model accessors and mutators. [this answer can help you](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/799#issuecomment-439821920)

Example:

```
// in the model
public function getProfilePictureAttribute()
{
   // Don't forget to check the relation here if you don't want any error on Nova.
   return $this->profile ? $this->profile->picture : null;
}

public function setProfilePictureAttribute($value)
{
   $profile = $this->profile;
   $profile->fill(['picture' => $value]);
   $profile->save();
}
// in the resource
Image::make('Profile picture')
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old... but for Nova 4, this could be easily done by adding ->required()...

```
HasOne::make('Address')->required(),
MorphOne::make('Address')->required(),
```

etc... This will display the fields of second resource on the same page, and insert/update accordingly.